# How do i defeat cell phone spyware?

Tags: malware, phone, spoofing, smartphone

I've bought a new phone, where one of its products can be activated by receiving a phone call. If someone uses a spoofed SIM card - with a number I recognize - I'll likely answer the call.

Are there ways to circumvent this? I'm currently using a phone for data only, and another for calls and SMS: This leaves my calls and texts subject to eavesdropping.

Would reinstalling the phone's OS weekly be a solution? Perhaps there's another way?

Comment: How about getting rid of the "product that can be activated by an incoming call"!

Answer (score 4):

It largely depends on the handset that you have.  If it has an operating system that you can reinstall (such as Android), see if you can install a version without the carrier bloatware, or any extra software that you don't need.

If you, as you suggest, re-install your OS, then you'd normally won't have a product that "can be activated just by being called".  If that's the case, then you have some serious malware issues.